# How to find the $k$th smallest item among the union of $C$ disjoint, sorted arrays?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

There is an explanation here https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20944/select-in-union-of-sorted-arrays-already-known but I find it very unclear.

Is there a more rigorously-outlined and easily-understood algorithm for how to find the $k$th smallest item among $C$ disjoint, sorted arrays?

Comment: I really believe this question doesn't belong here - you should ask it in cstheory.stackexchange.com. However, I'm worried why can't I flag it to migrate it there...

Comment: is python ok for a solution language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, at any given time we have to simultaneously compare the smallest item of all the arrays, find the smallest, and then incrementally update it. We want a heap, basically.

Let A[i] be the ith array, and A[i][j] is the jth element of that array. Sorted so that A[i][0] is the smallest of the ith array. Let H be a min heap, and let I be another array of length C.

```
I = [0] * C
array = [(A[i][0], i) for i in range(C)]
H = heapify(array)
```

In the heap the tuple is sorted lexicographically, i.e. sorted by the first element in the tuple. Next, we do this:

```
for i in range(k-1):
    z = H.peek()[1] # which array smallest came from
    I[z] += 1 # update index for that array
    H.replace((A[z][I[z]], z)) # remove smallest, update

k_smallest = H.peek()[0]
```

It's python, except that I'm pretending that python actually had a good heap. The idea is to maintain a heap with size equal to the number of arrays, with the smallest current element from each array. Each time we pop the smallest, and grab the next element from that array. That way, each array always one "representative" in the heap, and we're always assured that the top of the heap is the smallest of all the elements we haven't processed. We discard the first k-1, and then peek at the kth.

Running time: heap operations will cost O(log(C)), and you'll have to do it k times, so O(klog(C)). However, you also have to create the heap initially, so it totals to O( klog(C) + C).

Edit: my previous solution was actually O( (k + C) log(C)), because of heap creation. I now changed heap creation to a single "heapify" which only costs C.

Comment: This is just a n-way merge, which is not the optimal way to find the kth item in a union. For example, its possible to find the median of 2 sorted arrays in log(n) time, but using your method (merge) it will be O(n). Bad

Comment: Whether it's good or bad depends on k. If k is small relative to N, then my way works very well. In your version, k is proportional to both C and N, so it's much larger. I'm well aware of the median of 2 sorted arrays algorithm. If you can generalize it to answer the question with good bounds, then you should post an answer, and then we can compare complexity bounds.

Comment: well the link given in the original question generalizes the median of two sorted arrays algorithm for C sorted arrays and arbitrary k. Anyways, it's simple to generalize even without reading that link.

Comment: and btw, you shouldn't assume k is small. k is O(n).

Comment: The link gives a complexity bound of C log(k). This  is not strictly better than C + klog(C). In fact, if k is small and C is large, the algorithm I give will be faster.

Comment: I'm not assuming anything, I gave a solution that works for any k. You should not assume that k is O(n), it depends on the problem description. It is totally reasonable that there could be multiple complexity parameters for a problem. The question was to give a more easily understood algorithm for solving the problem then what the link gave, which I did.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81749/discussion-between-gen-y-s-and-nir-friedman).